# Getting "Error: invalid_client" after the application migrated to use Google OAuth2

Tags: oauth, google-openid, google-oauth, google-api-console

My application is using Microsoft ACS namespace to integrate with Google login. It was using Google OpenID 2.0, but now it has been updated to Google OpenID Connect. 
I have set up OAuth 2.0 in the Google Developer Console, such as creating a project, creating a new Client ID, and etc. After I have updated the ACS namespace with the new values of Client ID and Client secret, my application became working not stably. I am getting the following error on some Google accounts, but not for others (which means some Google accounts are working without any issue):

> 401. That’s an error. 
>      **Error: invalid_client** 
>       no support email

I can confirm that I have added a product name and an email address under: Apps & auths -> consent screen.

I have even tried to create a second Client ID under my project, and updated the ACS namespace to use the values from the second Client ID. But no luck.

I really don't know what I am missing, or if it is an issue related to Google console.

Comment: check again you haven't added the email for that project.  The Google Error message doesn't lie.

Comment: @DaImTo, I have double-checked that I can see the email has been added under APIs & auth -> Consent screen. And if it hasn't been set, how could some other Google accounts can sign in without any issue?

Comment: This has been fixed by creating a new Client ID. But this time, before I actually created it, I double-checked that the email is there, then created it. This time, it worked. 
I am still not quite sure what's wrong before, because I have created the client id multiple time. It gives me feeling like Google console is very timing sensitive between the time to create the Client ID, and the time to set the email.

Comment: It is very important to add the email and the project before doing anything else.   http://www.daimto.com/registering-a-project-with-google/